# AWS / ElasticBeanstalk - Autoscaling based on disk space utilisation?

Tags: amazon-web-services

ENV - AWS ElasticBeanstalk multi container

I have put custom metric "disk space utilisation" via configs in .ebextensions in cloudwatch. How can i ensure that ASG launches a new instance when a alarm(diskspaceutil > 90%) triggers on the currently launched instances & attaches the same alarm to newly launched instance?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Update the existing alarm and then add the policy ARN in `--alarm-actions` parameter.

Use the [put-metric-alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-alarm.html) command for this.

**Note : You will have to give all the original parameters to update the alarm as they are overwritten.**

BTW You can get the alarm parameters using [describe-alarm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarms.html)